Machine restarting
My Windows 11 machine constantly reboots. I have no idea why..  It's a machine in the power room, not overloaded and the temperatures are average
I checked WhoCrashed and get this
Crash dumps are enabled on your computer.
Crash dump directories:
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\Minidump
No valid crash dumps have been found on your computer.
Crash dumps are enabled but no valid crash dumps have been found. In case you are experiencing system crashes, it may be that crash dumps are prevented from being written out
The following is in the event viewer:
System event id 41:
"The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."
image
image
image

As Greg Askew mentions in comments, if you have a UPS, probably your UPS batteries are shot and should be replaced. My own experience is that a UPS with purely dead batteries will take over on a single cycle dropout, and then die after half a second, making the machine it's plugged into far more sensitive to a single-cycle outage than it would be without a UPS. Failing that, I'd look at replacing the PSU, as even new hardware can ship with dead or flaky components.

Some of the comments are missing but I was hoping to still ask for some help.  I had a technician change the batteries inside the UPS (under warranty)  and now the server is plugged directly into the 220v mains.  It's exhibiting the same of random power loss.  Is there anything I can do to test if it's true an issue with the mains , or does it look like a power supply issue?

We can assume at this point that the UPS is solid; if it still exhibits this problem when plugged into the repaired UPS, then the most likely problem is the system power supply unit. The only way we could isolate it further is with a mains power monitor and a 12V power monitor for inside the case. For most systems, replacing the power supply unit is much cheaper.

Currently the system is plugged into mains, not the UPS.  Should I try the UPS again?     Was thinking to use a small NUC/PI3 I have to see if it also goes down at the same time.

Plug it into the UPS, pull the UPS plug out of the wall. If the computer reboots, the UPS is at fault, repaired or no. But my money would definitely be on the power supply at this point. The NUC uses an external power supply, if it's a very short outage that's causing this it'll just sail right through. Worth a try, though, in case it's totally not power-related.

Good point about the NUC.
I'm away from home at the moment but I can still manage the PC. It is main connected at the moment and went down yesterday.  When I get home, i'll try the UPS test.   Should I try a mains power monitor or a 12v power monitor? Do I need to test both?
It would seem to me that bypassing hte UPS that the system still exhibits the same behaviour then PS issue?

Unplugging the UPS while the PC is plugged into it is a way of testing both UPS and PSU. But you are right, if it is plugged into mains power and is still behaving the same, it almost certainly is PSU, and those should be relatively inexpensive.

I have another UPS that it's plugged into right now and it's been up for 9 days. Going to wait a bit longer to see if it stays up.    Maybe the power has been "cleaner" lately and no spikes or phase loss?  THen I'll move to over to the previous UPS (Brand new CyberPower) and try out the test that tsc_chazz wrote...
Is it possible that brand new power supplies have random fall outs like this?  It doesn't appear to be a load issue as there is 1 SSD and 1 HDD.

"Infant mortality" in consumer hardware is not as common as it was a while back, but yes, it does happen.

Been running 12 days now. Waiting for a reboot to move it back to the original UPS
